# Clockwise vs. counter-clockwise rotation, usage of terms with complex machinery as with pumps and motors

Tags: motors, pumps

This question might be considered off-topic, because it will elicit opinions. However, I think it is somehow important to know about unwritten agreements, so I give it a try.

I know that the direction of rotation of electrical motors is defined as seen from the shaft side. This is also true for centrifugal pumps.

**Edit** Of course this rule applies for devices with only one usable shaft end. Motors with two usable shaft ends are not my concern here.

So when you see a typical combination of an asynchronous motor and a pump in most cases the pump will turn clockwise and the motor counter-clockwise by definition.

If I'm wrong here already, please correct.

There are dozens of pumps at my new workplace (on a ship) all of which turn clockwise as far as I know now. Hence the motors turn CCW. I was very bewildered to find out, that the VFDs driving the motors showed clockwise operations on their display. The the wires between the VFDs and the motors were swapped on all pumps. I think this was done to show the direction of rotation of the pump to an observer of the VFD.

**Edit** Most pumps here consume 10 or many more kW, so they have  three phase motors.

However I fell for it. Being an EE I had to install a new VFD where the old one already had been removed for repair. The wires had been marked but I did not trust them as the marking was partially lost and checked all boxes and switches between the VFD and the motor. I then connected all wiring to establish the "correct" order of phases. Of all things the body of the pump I was working on was concealed by thermal insulation so I could not see the embossed arrow. I assumed that if all VFDs showed clockwise operation the motor will do the same, as the VFD is driving the motor and not the pump.

After starting it up we had extensive cavitation and only one third of the pressure we'd expected. As my colleagues never had heard a pump turning the wrong direction we needed some time to find the root cause, but luckily the pump survived.

Apart from the fact that I had failed to check one single parameter of many, I'd understand that e.g. in a visualisation of a PLC the direction of rotation must be displayed for the pump and not the motor. But in my opinion the VFD itself should indicate the direction for the motor only, and phases should not been swapped if the direction of rotation can be controlled by programming the VFD.

**Is it common practice to make VFDs show the direction of rotation for the pump and not the motor and to achieve this by swapping the phases? And if so, what is the reasoning behind that?**
I could have asked this on EE.SE as well, but I think I know their answer and thought non EEs might have a different view on this.

Comment: “The shaft side”… when a motor has shafts at both ends…

Comment: Bench grinders have shafts at both ends - lots and lots of those…

Comment: @SolarMike I'm referring to motors with a shaft for a single load on one end. I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Are these 3-phase ? If so then direction of rotation should ALWAYS be checked as the position of windings get changed when the motor is rebuilt.

The DoR is easily changed on 3 phase motors by swapping any two phases.

Comment: In what sense does this answer my question?